# Converting Northing and Easting to Lat and lon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert

I have a shapefile and I want to export it to a CSV file, with the difference, that I want it to have Lat and Lon instead or in addition to the easting and northing columns. I've tried changing the CRS setting but so far no result.

Comment: Did u search a bit on gis.stackexchange ? (no ...)

Answer (score 5):

Don't change the CRS in the layer settings. If you already changed it, change it back to the original CRS. Once the layer is back in the correct, original CRS, you can add coordinates to the attribute table.

Use the Field Calculator to add two new fields with these expressions:

```
x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:current', 'EPSG:target'))
y(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:current', 'EPSG:target'))
```

- Find the EPSG code of the layer's CRS. Substitute this value where my expression says `'EPSG:current'`.
- Find the EPSG code of the CRS you want coordinates in. Substitute this value where my expression says `'EPSG:target'`. For latitude and longitude, use `'EPSG:4326'`

Or as MrXSquared pointed out, you can use the `layer_property` function instead.

```
x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))
```

Note: I assumed this is a point layer. If it's a line or polygon layer, you will need to modify the expressions in order to obtain point coordinates. Eg, using functions like `centroid()`, `start_point()`, `end_point()`, etc.

Comment: or use `x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))` so you dont need to look it up.

Comment: @MrXsquared Thanks. I added your suggestion to my answer.